# How to clear only a part of the screen?

Tags: android

I am using SurfaceHolder to draw in the canvas. I want to know how can I clear only part of the screen, or how can I draw animation only part of the screen? I don't want to draw in all the screean, can I do it only part of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw to only a part of the screen, first specify two rects. Like this:

```
Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
Rect dst = new Rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

Then you just draw using the drawBitmap method that takes two rects as parameters.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, null);
```

Say that you have a background image thats 100*100 px. Then the code above would redraw only the top left corner of that bitmap.